# C# - Operator ‘==’ cannot be applied to operands of type ‘char’ and ‘string’

Tags: c#, string, char

I know there is a question similar to this one but the naswers there didnt help me that much it was compicated so i asked this new one

i was trying to convert char into upper case by .ToUpper method

but it is give me this issue

```
Operator ‘==’ cannot be applied to operands of type ‘char’ and ‘string’
```

here is the code

```
char UserChoice = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
char upperCaseChoice = Char.ToUpperInvariant(UserChoice);

if (UserChoice == "Y" || upperCaseChoice == "YES")
{
    TotalCoffeeCost = askForCoffee(TotalCoffeeCost); //Note here that we did not set invalidChoice to false, meaning it will loop again
}
else if (upperCaseChoice == "N" || upperCaseChoice == "NO")
{
    invalidChoice = false;
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.WriteLine(" Please enter a valid choice");
}
```

Comment: You're explicitly converting a line of input to a single character, and then comparing that character to strings. It looks like you actually want your input as a string, and convert the _string_ to uppercase.

Comment: no i want a char only , can i give the input as a string and then convert into char an then pass the argument, will it work

Comment: " denotes a string, ' denotes a character. Clearly `upperCaseChoice == "YES"` is impossible (a single character cannot match 3 characters). You seem to want `UserChoice == 'Y'`. Also note that common convention dictates that local variables should be camelCase not PascalCase.

Comment: sorry its not UserChoice in the first argument in the if statement, its upperCaseChoice

Comment: FYI `char` is short for "character". "YES" is a string composed of 3 characters. "NO" is a string composed of 2 characters.

Comment: so like i have to only stroe 3 or 2 char what can i use instaed of string or char where the bytes are lower

Comment: "what can I use instead of string" - please clarify why you don't want to use string. String is the exact correct thing to use here.

Comment: its not compulsary to use  char , i was playing with datatypes as i was learning c# , so i think why not use a lower byte datatype to just store 2 or 3 char

Comment: before i was using int to just store values just upto 30  so then i used bytes instead of int becuse the values was not going up from 30 i was sure that i dont need int to store numbers here , so i was trying to do the same thing here

Comment: as you need to store `yes` or `no`, using `string` is reasonable here.

Comment: FYI, the string `YES` will take up 6 bytes in memory, the char `Y` will take up 2, that's a 4 byte difference, not 4 kilobytes or 4 megabytes, 4 bytes, that is the definition of negligible

Comment: "why not use a lower byte datatype to just store 2 or 3 char" - OK, let's assume that you're just storing one char. You're currently calling `Console.ReadLine()`, this returns a `string`. You're then calling `Convert.ToChar` to get the first character from that string. So you have multiple pieces of data in memory: the length of the string, its characters, and this new single character. Now, with .NET's garbage collection, it will still be a while before the data from the original string gets expunged. Therefore, you're actually using more memory in the time until that gets GC'd.

Comment: How a char could be "Yes" then? Declare upperCaseChoice as string

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the type of the variable to a character, set it to a string.

```
string UserChoice = Console.ReadLine();

if (UserChoice == "y")
{
    Console.WriteLine("test");
}
```

Comment: im doing char intentionally , i was using string before and it was working fine , but as i thought if i have to get only yes or no or y and n why not to use char instead of string

Comment: @Indie "only yes or no or y or n" - yes is a string composed of 3 chars, no is a string composed of 2 chars.

Comment: By definition, "yes" and "no" are not individual characters -- they are strings made up of individual characters.

Comment: Single-character string is still a string, an immutable reference type with instance properties such as Length and an array of characters. A char is a 16-bit integer. The .NET designers probably felt that comparing the two is most probably an issue with the code and so they did not introduce such comparison. There's only handful of strings that can ever compare to a single character, it's similar as if single-element arrays of int would support comparing to ints. You can easily fix this by doing 'y' (char literal) instead of "y" (string literal).

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the following method?

```
    // original string
    string UserChoice = Console.ReadLine();

    // string converted to Upper case
    string upperCaseChoice = UserChoice.ToUpper();



    if (UserChoice == "Y" || upperCaseChoice == "YES")
    {
        //Do Somthing

    }
    else if (upperCaseChoice == "N" || upperCaseChoice == "NO")
    {
        //Do Somthing
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine(" Please enter a valid choice");
    }
```

In the first step you cannot convert the string to a character because Character refers to a single character value
You must convert the value to an array of characters

```
    var userChoice = Console.ReadLine().ToCharArray();

    var userChoiceFirstChar = Convert.ToString(userChoice.First()).ToUpperInvariant();
    var userChoiceJoin = string.Join("", userChoice).ToUpper();

    
    if (userChoiceFirstChar == "Y" || userChoiceJoin == "YES")
    {
    }
    else if (userChoiceFirstChar == "N" || userChoiceJoin == "NO")
    {
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine(" Please enter a valid choice");
    }
```

Comment: What if the user typed a lower case "y"? - just ignore "UserChoice" and only check "upperCaseChoice"

Answer (score 0):

Well, `string` is a *collection* of `char`acters and that's why the fragment below doesn't compile:

```
char upperCaseChoice = ... // single character

...
// how come can compiler compare single character with a collection?

if ( ... upperCaseChoice == "YES" ...)
```

I suggest to *extract method*, let it be `ReadBool` which takes the `title` (the question we'll put for users) and returns `bool` (`true` or `false`) user's answer:

```
private static readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<string, bool> s_Bools = 
  new Dictionary<string, bool>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) {
    //TODO: add more synonyms, like `{"true", true}`, `{"OK", true}` etc.
    {"y",   true},
    {"yes", true},
    {"n",   false},
    {"no",  false}, 
};

private static bool ReadBool(string title) {
  // keep asking user until known response is provided
  while (true) {
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(title)) 
      Console.WriteLine(title);

    // if we know the response for user's input, return it
    // .Trim() - let's be nice and tolerate leading and trailing spaces
    if (s_Bools.TryGetValue(Console.ReadLine().Trim(), out bool result))
      return result;

    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.WriteLine(" Please enter a valid choice"); 
  }
}
```

Then you can use it as simple as

```
if (ReadBool("Please, make your choice (yes/no)")) {
  //TODO: Relevant code for "Yes"
}
else {
  //TODO: Relevant code for "No"
}
```